# Error due to delay operator in algorithm section

Tags: delay, modelica, openmodelica

I have implemented  a delay operator in algorithm section of a class as shown in the test case below, but during the execution of the codes in Open modelica, I face the below error. how can I fix the problem?

```
 model test3
     Real x=sin(377*time);
     Real z;
     parameter Real tau[:]={0.01,0.02};

  equation

  algorithm
     for k in 1: 2 loop
        z:=delay(x,tau[k]);

     end for;

    end test3;
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a tool issue. On the other hand, why would you calculate z for k=1 and never use it?

Answer (score 2):

Like tbeu said in his answer, its an issue in OpenModelica. In Dymola your example simulates as expected. So please report the issue [here](https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica#BugReporting).

Investigating a bit I realized that the following combination prevents your model from translating:

- usage of delay
- in an algorithm section
- inside a for loop

Hence, you have to get rid of either of those.

#### Workarounds

If you know the size of `tau[:]` in advance, use **separate lines** for the computation of `z` instead of the for loop:

```
model sep_lines
  Real x = sin(8 * time);
  Real z[2];
  parameter Real tau[2] = {0.02, 0.01};
equation

algorithm
  z[1] := delay(x, tau[1]);
  z[2] := delay(x, tau[2]);
end sep_lines;
```

Maybe you can use an **equation section** instead of the algoirthm section. Then you don't need the for loop at all, since function calls (in this case the `delay`) are vectorized automatically if needed. Your code will reduce to:

```
model eqs
  Real x = sin(8 * time);
  Real z[3];
  parameter Real tau[3] = {0.03, 0.02, 0.01};
equation
  z = delay(x, tau);
end eqs;
```

#### Extra issue

If the for loop is replaced with a **while loop** the model translates and simulates. But **the delayed signal `z[1]` is not correct** and the error increases with the frequency of `x`. At low frequencies like 1 Hz its barely visible, but with a frequency of e.g. 20 Hz the amplitude is considerably wrong. So don't get fooled by this solution.

```
model while_ "Compiles, but the amplitude of z[1] is wrong"
   Real x = sin(2*Modelica.Constants.pi * 20 * time);
   Real z[size(tau, 1)];
   parameter Real tau[:] = {0.02, 0.01};
 protected
   Integer i;
 algorithm
   i := 0;
   while i < size(tau, 1) loop
     i := i + 1;
     z[i] := delay(x, tau[i]);
   end while;
 end while_;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in OpenModelica. A ticket for it was created: https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica/ticket/5572