# Can not assign values to an array when using sample() function

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I'm trying to implement a DFT on my own because the FFT example in OpenModelica is not working for me and I can't figure out why.
But I'm already stuck sampling a sine function and assigning the sampled values to a buffer array.
This is why I tried to make it even simpler and just assign a counter variable "iTick" to the array which still doesn't work.
See the basic example.

Can anyone tell me why this is not working and how I can actually assign a value to the array when using the sample() function ??

```
block DFT
  import Modelica.Constants.pi;

  parameter Integer N = 360 "Total number of samples";

  Integer iTick;
  Real y_buf[N];


algorithm

when sample(0, 0.1) then     
  iTick :=iTick + 1;

  if iTick >= 1 and iTick <= N then
    y_buf[iTick] := iTick;
  end if;
end when;

end DFT;
```

```
[358] 14:56:15 Symbolisch Warnung
The linear system: 
1 : $PRE.y_buf[2] = y_buf[2]
2 : y_buf[2] = $PRE.y_buf[2]
[
  -1.0 , 1.0 ;
  1.0 , -1.0
]
  *
[
  y_buf[2] ;
  $PRE.y_buf[2]
]
  =
[
  0.0 ;
  0.0
]
 might be structurally or numerically singular for variable $PRE.y_buf[2] since U(2,2) = 0.0. It might be hard to solve. Compilation continues anyway.

[359] 14:56:15 Symbolisch Warnung
The linear system: 
1 : $PRE.y_buf[1] = y_buf[1]
2 : y_buf[1] = $PRE.y_buf[1]
[
  -1.0 , 1.0 ;
  1.0 , -1.0
]
  *
[
  y_buf[1] ;
  $PRE.y_buf[1]
]
  =
[
  0.0 ;
  0.0
]
 might be structurally or numerically singular for variable $PRE.y_buf[1] since U(2,2) = 0.0. It might be hard to solve. Compilation continues anyway.

[360] 14:56:15 Übersetzung Warnung
Assuming fixed start value for the following 2 variables:
         y_buf[360]:DISCRETE(fixed = false )  type: Real  [360]
         iTick:DISCRETE(fixed = false )  type: Integer
```

Comment: Your code works fine in Dymola 2020, so it seems this is related to the tool...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "Symbolisch Warnung" disappears once you initialize `iTick` and `y_buf`. However, the code still does not work. OpenModelica simulates it, but the items of `y_buf` are never updated.

This issue might be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56916012/error-due-to-delay-operator-in-algorithm-section) question  where the `delay` operator is not working in algorithm sections. Therefore, I suggest a similar workaround: Try to avoid the algorithm section. With an equation section and proper initialization, your minimal example could look as follows:

```
block DFT
  import Modelica.Constants.pi;

  parameter Integer N = 360 "Total number of samples";

  Integer iTick(start=0, fixed=true);
  Real y_buf[N](start=fill(0, N), fixed=fill(true, N));

equation 

  when sample(0, 0.1) then
    iTick = pre(iTick) + 1;
  end when;

  for i in 1:N loop
    when iTick >= i then
      y_buf[i] =  iTick;
    end when;
  end for;

end DFT;
```

Comment: Thank you very much marco! It's unfortunate that the issue is related to OpenModelica, because I have to use it. And your answer is still a bit strange to me, because I'm only used to programming languages, but it definitely works!

Comment: Modelica models can have equation sections and algorithm sections. The code in algorithm sections is executed "as is", like in other programming languages from top to bottom. Equation sections enable you to define mathematical equations, which the Modelica tool are re-arranges if necessary. Hence, in equation sections the causality of the equations and their order of execution is not known until the model is translated. On https://modelica.org/publications many books and some freely available tutorials are listed, which should explain these fundamental concepts of Modelica.

Answer (score 3):

After a long search and try and error I found out that the magic word "discrete" solves my problem! I can't yet explain why, but see below the working example:

```
model Test
  import Modelica.Constants.pi;

  parameter Integer N = 360 "Total number of samples";

  Integer iTick(start=0, fixed=true);
  discrete Real y_buf[N](start=fill(0,N), fixed=fill(true, N));


algorithm

when sample(0, 0.1) then     
  iTick :=iTick + 1;

  if iTick >= 1 and iTick <= N then
    y_buf[iTick] := iTick;
  end if;
end when;
end Test;
```

Hopefully this is a help to someone!

Comment: Nice! Definitely better than my answer. I guess Dymola declares variables automatically as discrete if necessary, so that could be the reason why the code in your question only worked in Dymola, but not in OpenModelica.